Как проверить, существует ли ключ JSON при парсинге? (java)
Должны обрабатываться объекты двух типов: с полем ifDryer и без него.
Код:
try {
    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(filePath));
    JSONArray prs = (JSONArray) obj;

    for (Object product : prs) {
        JSONObject jsonProduct = (JSONObject) product;

        String name = (String) jsonProduct.get("name");
        long weight = (Long) jsonProduct.get("weight");
        long price = (Long) jsonProduct.get("price");
        Date delivering = new Date((long) jsonProduct.get("delivering"));

        JSONObject extraDetails = (JSONObject) jsonProduct.get("extraDetails");
        System.out.println(extraDetails);

        if (extraDetails == null) {
            Product newpr = new Product(name, weight, price, delivering);
            products.add(newpr);
        } else if (extraDetails.containsKey("ifDryer")) {
            boolean ifDryer = (boolean) extraDetails.get("ifDryer");
            WashingMashine newpr = new WashingMashine(name, weight, price, delivering, ifDryer);
            products.add(newpr);
        }
    }

сам json:
[
    {
        "name": "Sumsung",
        "weight": 30,
        "price": 1,
        "delivering": 19509,
        "ifDryer": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Anno",
        "weight": 30,
        "price": 3,
        "delivering": 19509
    },
    {
        "name": "Zegbee",
        "weight": 30,
        "price": 7,
        "delivering": 19509
    }
]

Проблема: программа не видит поле ifDryer

Не видит или не смотрит? В чем проблема?

@Arc, укажите, какая именно библиотека используется для парсинга JSON.  Возникает ли какая-то ошибка при парсинге?

Представленный код проверяет наличие поля ifDryer внутри вложенного объекта extraDetails, тогда как показанный JSON не содержит такого вложенного объекта и соответственно к полю можно обращаться напрямую:
// ...
Date delivering = new Date((long) jsonProduct.get("delivering"));

Product newPr;

if (jsonProduct.containsKey("ifDryer")) {
    boolean ifDryer = (boolean) extraDetails.get("ifDryer");
    newPr = new WashingMashine(name, weight, price, delivering, ifDryer);
} else {
    newPr = new Product(name, weight, price, delivering);
}
products.add(newPr);

